# how to calculate strlen except <br> special characters?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

```
$productstr = "Nodrive <br> testing the functionality"
 strlen( $productstr ) > 14 ? substr( $productstr, 0, 14 )."..." : $productstr,
```

Problem is `br` is also counting as a character and displaying the

```
Nodrive
...
```

I need the solution to not count `br` is a letter. I need to display

```
NoDrive ...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strip the html tags before you calculate the length.

Comment: Calculate the strlen of `str_replace('<br>', $productstr)`. Or if you need more, use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Answer (score 3):

```
$productstr = strip_tags("Nodrive <br> testing the functionality")
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the 
 tag by using preg_replace function.
And if your string does contain more html tags like it you can use strip_tags function as well to remove html tags from the description and display plain text.

```
$productstr = "Nodrive <br> testing the functionality";
$productstrexceptbr = preg_replace(' <br>', '', $productstr);
strlen( $productstrexceptbr ) > 14 ? substr( $productstrexceptbr, 0, 14 )."..." : $productstrexceptbr,
```